# sqlite, values not seen in Loop

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, android-sqlite

This is my data class

```
  data class DatabaseData(
        val groente: String,
        val rangeValues: MutableList<Int>,
        val oogstPeriode: String, 
        val oogstStart: String, 
        val oogstEind: String 
         ) {
        fun add(value: Int): DatabaseData {`your text`
        this.rangeValues.add(value)
        return this
        }
        }
```

and this is the corresponding query. It gathers all groentes with the same name, with the corresponding  selected_start, selected_end and is_range. it calaculates the right numbers and the numbers are added to a single groente. Problem is that it doesnt see part of de values that are in
the if.... do

```
 fun getSavedGroentes(): List<DatabaseData> {
        val groentesWithDetails = mutableListOf<DatabaseData>()
        val groenteRanges = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Int>>()

        val query = """
        SELECT OOGSTSCHEMA.groente,
           OOGSTSCHEMA.selected_start,
           OOGSTSCHEMA.selected_end,
           OOGSTSCHEMA.is_range,
           OOGSTSCHEMA.oogstperiode,
           BASIS_DATA.oogststart,
           BASIS_DATA.oogsteind
           FROM OOGSTSCHEMA
          JOIN BASIS_DATA ON OOGSTSCHEMA.groente = BASIS_DATA.groente
           """.trimIndent()

          val cursor = readableDatabase.rawQuery(query, null)
          cursor.use {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                    val groente = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex("groente"))

                    val oogstStart = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex("oogststart"))
                    val oogstEind = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex("oogsteind"))
                    val oogstPeriode = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex("oogstperiode"))

                    val selectedStart = it.getInt(it.getColumnIndex("selected_start"))
                    val selectedEnd = it.getInt(it.getColumnIndex("selected_end"))
                    val isRange = it.getInt(it.getColumnIndex("is_range")) == 1

                    if (groenteRanges.containsKey(groente)) {
                        val rangeValues = if (isRange) {
                            (selectedStart..selectedEnd).toList()
                        } else {
                            listOf(selectedStart)
                        }
                        groenteRanges[groente]?.addAll(rangeValues)
                    } else {
                        val rangeValues = if (isRange) {
                            (selectedStart..selectedEnd).toMutableList()
                        } else {
                            mutableListOf(selectedStart, selectedEnd)
                        }
                        groenteRanges[groente] = rangeValues
                    }
                } while (it.moveToNext())

                groenteRanges.forEach { (groente, rangeValues) ->
                    val databaseData = DatabaseData(
                        groente,
                        rangeValues,
                        oogstPeriode,
                        oogstStart,
                        oogstEind
                    )
                    groentesWithDetails.add(databaseData)
                }
            } else {
                // Handle empty result set
                Log.d("Database", "No data found in OOGSTSCHEMA table")
            }
          }
          Log.d("Database", "groentesWithDetails : $groentesWithDetails")
          return groentesWithDetails
          }
```

```
     For some reason these are greyed out   
     val oogstStart = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex("oogststart"))
```

```
  val oogstEind = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex("oogsteind"))
          val oogstPeriode = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex("oogstperiode"))
```

`

causing unresolved reference errors here   oogstPeriode, oogstStart,oogstEind

Did I miss some {}? I cant figure iy out

only way to "fix it" was by putting them outside the Loop, but obviously that isnt a solution`

Comment: They're greyed out because you've defined them as local variables inside the `do` loop. Hence, they're invisible outside.